# Signing CSR with an alternatively-encrypted key

Tags: openssl, gnupg

I have a PEM-encoded RSA private-key that's encrypted with something other than OpenSSL. I'd like to sign a CSR with it. However, this requires me to decrypt it first. However, as the -signkey argument to "openssl x509 -req" takes a file, the encrypted key must first be decrypted.

Is there a way to avoid writing the decrypted key to disk first? I am not going to be able to.

Comment: Have you tried `openssl req -new -passin pass:yourpassword -passout pass:yourpassword -key /path/to/your/key_file -out /path/to/your/csr_file -days 365` ?

Comment: That only works when OpenSSL has encrypted it. In this case, something else has encrypted it...

Comment: Never tried, but I think the only way is to modify the encrypted RSA-key file by adding the headers (-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----, Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED, DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,5B01E932988DC66B) so that openssl could recognize the encryption algorithm and decrypt the key. You may use a script to do that.

Answer (score 1):

YES, you just need to use a shell with **process substitution** available: for instance zsh or bash, on Unix/Linux or Windows (cygwin).

With such a shell, you can use the following syntax, for some arguments that should normally be file names:

```
<(my_program_or_shell_command)
```

This way, the shell creates a **named pipe** and replaces the argument with the file name of this pipe. The content of this pseudo file is read from the output of `my_program_or_shell_command`.

For instance, you can display the current date this way (every examples in this answer are for Windows with cygwin - this could be done on Unix/Linux the same way, with same syntax, but the named pipes would not appear with the same format):

```
% cat <(date)
sam.  5 août 2017 01:33:06
```

To understand how it works, use `echo` to display command line parameters:

```
% echo <(date)
/dev/fd/63
```

As you can see, the command `echo` sees a file name as first parameter. But this is not a real file. We use `ls` instead of `echo` to display the file type:

```
% ls -l <(date)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 fenyo None 0  5 août  01:34 /dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[400]
```

So, this is a named pipe.

Therefore, we can now answer your question:

> Is there a way to avoid writing the decrypted key to disk first?

Yes. Let's suppose that:

- the PEM encoded private key, once encrypted, is named `private-key.pem.crypt`
- the program or command line that can decrypt this file is `my_personal_decrypt_program -myoption private-key.pem.crypt`
- this program or command line writes the decrypted content on its standard output

You can now launch:

```
openssl req -new [...] -signkey <(my_personal_decrypt_program -myoption private-key.pem.crypt)
```

**This way, openssl sees a file name just after `-signkey`, but it is not a real file, it is a pipe, whose content is the output of `my_personal_decrypt_program -myoption value`. So, there is nothing written to a persistent storage, like a filesystem based on a disk. Everything is done in memory (kernel memory and userland memory).**

Finally, be careful that in some situations, even without any secret in a file on a persistent storage, the `openssl` process (that stores your private key in its userland memory, to be able to compute the CSR) could be swapped on a swap partition. For instance, this way, in case of a lack of memory, the private key could be written into the swap. Thus, avoid using any type of paging or swapping device, if you expect a really high level of security.

Even without the `openssl` process being swapped, the same security flaw could occur for the pipe content (which is stored temporarily inside kernel memory) on a system with a swappable kernel (Linux and *BSD kernels are not swappable, so no problem with these operating systems). This is another good reason to avoid kernel memory swapping (Windows for instance, that can swap some parts of its kernel, in its so-called pagefile => disable this feature to get high level of confidence in your system).